# How to get only the Process name using Process ID in unix

Tags: shell, unix, process, command

I want to get the process name(not the entire process information) when I have the process ID.The command I need should only return the process name.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
ps --pid <pid> -o cmd h
```

where

```
--pid <pid>        specifies the process' PID
-o cmd             tells ps to only print the command name
h                  suppresses headers
```

if you want the **command with all its arguments**; or

```
ps --pid <pid> -o comm h
```

if you want **only the executable name**.

Comment: Ya ,this is giving a string that contains the process name as an output.So now, how can I retrieve the exact process name from that string.I want the process name as the only output.

Comment: Which is the output you get?

Comment: I am getting below string string as an output to the command.But HIXI is my process name.So how can I get the process name only as the output?I need the command.    /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/u01/PT/HIXI/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/conf/log

Comment: Hey,Roberto please do suggest something.I am really stuck in the problem.

Comment: I expanded my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you system uses the /proc filesystem:

```
cut -d "" -f 1 /proc/$pid/cmdline
```